# Pseudo Block Driver: I have generated the device file for block driver using mknod

Tags: linux, block, linux-device-driver

I have generated the device file for block driver using mknod. Now how to read/write/transfer any request or file through my generated device file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through this sample block driver

```
sbd.c

/*
 * A sample, extra-simple block driver. Updated for kernel 2.6.31.
 *
 * (C) 2003 Eklektix, Inc.
 * (C) 2010 Pat Patterson <pat at superpat dot com>
 * Redistributable under the terms of the GNU GPL.
 */

#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/moduleparam.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

#include <linux/kernel.h> /* printk() */
#include <linux/fs.h>     /* everything... */
#include <linux/errno.h>  /* error codes */
#include <linux/types.h>  /* size_t */
#include <linux/vmalloc.h>
#include <linux/genhd.h>
#include <linux/blkdev.h>
#include <linux/hdreg.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");
static char *Version = "1.4";

static int major_num = 0;
module_param(major_num, int, 0);
static int logical_block_size = 512;
module_param(logical_block_size, int, 0);
static int nsectors = 1024; /* How big the drive is */
module_param(nsectors, int, 0);

/*
 * We can tweak our hardware sector size, but the kernel talks to us
 * in terms of small sectors, always.
 */
#define KERNEL_SECTOR_SIZE 512

/*
 * Our request queue.
 */
static struct request_queue *Queue;

/*
 * The internal representation of our device.
 */
static struct sbd_device {
    unsigned long size;
    spinlock_t lock;
    u8 *data;
    struct gendisk *gd;
} Device;

/*
 * Handle an I/O request.
 */
static void sbd_transfer(struct sbd_device *dev, sector_t sector,
        unsigned long nsect, char *buffer, int write) {
    unsigned long offset = sector * logical_block_size;
    unsigned long nbytes = nsect * logical_block_size;

    if ((offset + nbytes) > dev->size) {
        printk (KERN_NOTICE "sbd: Beyond-end write (%ld %ld)\n", offset, nbytes);
        return;
    }
    if (write)
        memcpy(dev->data + offset, buffer, nbytes);
    else
        memcpy(buffer, dev->data + offset, nbytes);
}

static void sbd_request(struct request_queue *q) {
    struct request *req;

    req = blk_fetch_request(q);
    while (req != NULL) {
        // blk_fs_request() was removed in 2.6.36 - many thanks to
        // Christian Paro for the heads up and fix...
        //if (!blk_fs_request(req)) {
        if (req == NULL || (req->cmd_type != REQ_TYPE_FS)) {
            printk (KERN_NOTICE "Skip non-CMD request\n");
            __blk_end_request_all(req, -EIO);
            continue;
        }
        sbd_transfer(&Device, blk_rq_pos(req), blk_rq_cur_sectors(req),
                req->buffer, rq_data_dir(req));
        if ( ! __blk_end_request_cur(req, 0) ) {
            req = blk_fetch_request(q);
        }
    }
}

/*
 * The HDIO_GETGEO ioctl is handled in blkdev_ioctl(), which
 * calls this. We need to implement getgeo, since we can't
 * use tools such as fdisk to partition the drive otherwise.
 */
int sbd_getgeo(struct block_device * block_device, struct hd_geometry * geo) {
    long size;

    /* We have no real geometry, of course, so make something up. */
    size = Device.size * (logical_block_size / KERNEL_SECTOR_SIZE);
    geo->cylinders = (size & ~0x3f) >> 6;
    geo->heads = 4;
    geo->sectors = 16;
    geo->start = 0;
    return 0;
}

/*
 * The device operations structure.
 */
static struct block_device_operations sbd_ops = {
        .owner  = THIS_MODULE,
        .getgeo = sbd_getgeo
};

static int __init sbd_init(void) {
    /*
     * Set up our internal device.
     */
    Device.size = nsectors * logical_block_size;
    spin_lock_init(&Device.lock);
    Device.data = vmalloc(Device.size);
    if (Device.data == NULL)
        return -ENOMEM;
    /*
     * Get a request queue.
     */
    Queue = blk_init_queue(sbd_request, &Device.lock);
    if (Queue == NULL)
        goto out;
    blk_queue_logical_block_size(Queue, logical_block_size);
    /*
     * Get registered.
     */
    major_num = register_blkdev(major_num, "sbd");
    if (major_num < 0) {
        printk(KERN_WARNING "sbd: unable to get major number\n");
        goto out;
    }
    /*
     * And the gendisk structure.
     */
    Device.gd = alloc_disk(16);
    if (!Device.gd)
        goto out_unregister;
    Device.gd->major = major_num;
    Device.gd->first_minor = 0;
    Device.gd->fops = &sbd_ops;
    Device.gd->private_data = &Device;
    strcpy(Device.gd->disk_name, "sbd0");
    set_capacity(Device.gd, nsectors);
    Device.gd->queue = Queue;
    add_disk(Device.gd);

    return 0;

out_unregister:
    unregister_blkdev(major_num, "sbd");
out:
    vfree(Device.data);
    return -ENOMEM;
}

static void __exit sbd_exit(void)
{
    del_gendisk(Device.gd);
    put_disk(Device.gd);
    unregister_blkdev(major_num, "sbd");
    blk_cleanup_queue(Queue);
    vfree(Device.data);
}

module_init(sbd_init);
module_exit(sbd_exit);
```

For Pseudo block device Also refer [this](http://www.ijceronline.com/papers/(NCASSGC)/E17-28.pdf)
Reference http://free-electrons.com/doc/block_drivers.pdf

Comment: Yeah in that pdf file i am not getting about those API used for read, write? What are they ?

Comment: To read and write to device which actually virtual (pseudo ) device

Comment: Then How to use them i am not getting, Means i have one folder containing Makefile and simple code Hello world.c and one file pblk.c which contains that all structure regarding that block driver. Now Step 1. make, Step 2. insmod .ko, Step 3. dmesg, messages i have seen from my pblk.c. Now how can i use this device file. The device file is generated implicitly in my /dev folder.

Comment: You can make sample driver to write on this driver using write API then in same program you can use read API to read whatever you have written before. So that should be printed on screen when you read

Comment: You can understand that something is written in file and something is reading from that

Comment: I didn't got, i have write API, a separate read API I have compiled it i got respective binary files of it, now what to do?

Comment: Nope you did n't get me you have to write both API in same file and run it

Comment: And in the API, in those fopen() and fwrite() function i have passed the module name. for eg: "./pblk" pblk is my name of module

Comment: I suggest that you should first learn pseudo driver . Which write on buffer can be shown on terminal and again read it from terminal.

Comment: Welcome .. If answer is useful you can upvote and accept it

Comment: While inserting a module of USB driver its showing an error an error is insmod: ERROR: could not insert module pen_usb.ko: Unknown symbol in module
Not having the reputation as 15